# Unable to start or Stop Tomcat on Linux Server

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, log4j, tomcat6

I'm unable to start or stop Tomcat on Linux. As the server is new and first time we are running it , shutdown.sh throws an exception below though I have placed the log4j.properties:

```
/tomcat/V6.0/bin$ ./shutdown.sh
After calling setenv.sh: Using JAVA_HOME:       
After calling setenv.sh: Using JRE_HOME:       /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_91/jre
After cygwin: Using JAVA_HOME:       
After cygwin: Using JRE_HOME:       /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_91/jre
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.sax).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

But when I run the startup.sh it doesnot show anything on console saying tomcat started. Only the below lines have been printed.

```
/tomcat/V6.0/bin$ ./startup.sh
After calling setenv.sh: Using JAVA_HOME:       
After calling setenv.sh: Using JRE_HOME:       /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_91/jre
After cygwin: Using JAVA_HOME:       
After cygwin: Using JRE_HOME:       /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_91/jre
```

Using localhost when I try launching the tomcat it throws 404 error
Please can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Please check the Java version on the Linux server. Also verify whether Tomcat 6.0 is compatible with Java 8 which is shown in the error.

Comment: Linux server is using JAVA 8 and tomcat 6.0 is compatible with JAVA 5 or LATER versions.

Comment: Try using `bin/catalina.sh run` instead of `bin/startup.sh`. That will run Tomcat without detaching stdout/stderr and you'll be able to see any errors that occur with the launch, even if they don't get logged to `logs/catalina.out`.

Comment: PS: Upgrade your Tomcat. Tomcat 6 has reached EOL and will receive no further security updates.

Comment: This is what I was getting when I tried running above command and aborted the operation                                                                           Java hotspot(tm) 64-bit server vm warning ignoring option permsize=256m support was removed in 8.0
java hotspot(tm) 64-bit server vm warning ignoring option permsize=256m support was removed in 8.0
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.sax).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

Comment: This was Client specification to use Tomcat 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will really suggest to upgrade tomcat, if it is mandatory then someone has to take the risk of the implementation, with that said lets list how to validate tomcat properly.

1. Review the tomcat 6 versions that you really need, this is the [list of tomcat 6 releases](http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-6/), if you are force to use tomcat 6.x then try to use the latest release in this case I would recommend [v.6.0.53](http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-6/v6.0.53/bin/apache-tomcat-6.0.53.zip)
2. Unzip the tomcat into your disk
3. Make sure that you give the execution permission to the `.sh` scripts that are in `bin` folder. For example if you are located at the bin folder of tomcat `apache-tomcat-6.0.53/bin$>` then you can run `chmod +x ./*.sh`
4. Make sure that `JAVA_HOME` is set
5. In your bin folder run the startup.sh script like this `./startup.sh`
6. Check if tomcat is running with this command `ps -ef | grep tomcat` it will list the running process that are related to tomcat.
7. Try to stop tomcat, in your `bin` folder run the shutdown script `./shutdow.sh`
8. Check if tomcat is running with this command `ps -ef | grep tomcat`, if you don't get listed the tomcat process then it is stopped successfully otherwise you can force the shutdown, using `kill - 9 <process-number>` so for example when you run `ps -ef | grep tomcat`

Sample output of ps-ef command

```
servername    4328     1  0 21:43 pts/1    00:00:07 /usr/var/jdk1.8.0_111/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=... tomcat
servername    4497  4117  0 22:07 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto tomcat
```

Then stop tomcat with this `kill -9 4328` it is because `4328` is the process number that you get from the `ps -ef` output.

> How access tomcat without port  number?

If you need to access your tomcat server through the browser with a default port number then configure the connector to http default port number 80.  Please see the following instructions:

1. Go to `apache-tomcat-6.0.53/conf` folder
2. Open `server.xml` file
3. Go to Connector  configuration, by default it look like this:

Default connector configuration

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

4. Change the port number to 80, like this:

Connector configuration with port number 80

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

5. Restart tomcat.  One observation here, only for linux.  The first 1024 ports are restricted  to root user, with this approach you can start tomcat only with root user.  There is another solution for this with iptables, only in a case when you have to start tomcat without root user, see this  post if you need to use port 80 and start tomcat without root user [redirect-port-80-to-8080-and-make-it-work-on-local](https://askubuntu.com/questions/444729/redirect-port-80-to-8080-and-make-it-work-on-local-machine#579540)

Comment: I tried the same way. But the problem is 'm unable to launch on web browser to check whether tomcat has really started. For eg: My hostname for Linux server is example.xxx.net. And after starting tomcat , I should go to the web browser and enter the hostname should really work right? But 'm facing connection refused error message. Is there anything 'm missing?

Comment: first try testing in the same server with `curl localhost:8080` assuming that your tomcat is running on port 8080.  the command should give an output with the html code of tomcat default homepage that means that tomcat is responding but if you go to other machine and is in the same network you can try with browser using the ipaddress for ex. `http://192.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080`

Comment: Is there any way to launch the application on web browser without port number? ( http://192.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080)

Comment: I have tried using the server config as per the direction above.Which didn't help me in resolving my issue. When I tried another way it threw the below error:/tomcat/V6.0/bin$ sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified